# WiX custom action on major upgrade rollback not run

Tags: wix, custom-action, rollback, major-upgrade

I have a WiX setup which has

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" 
  DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />
```

If an error during the upgrade occurs, the setup rolls back and restores the previously installed version. 
However, a scheduled task created via a custom action is lost and never restored.

The custom actions I'm using for creation/removal/rollback of the task are:

```
<!-- task scheduling -->
<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask" Return="check" Directory="SystemFolder"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /Create /RU &quot;[TASK_DOMAIN]\[TASK_USERNAME]&quot; /RP [TASK_PASSWORD] /SC DAILY /TN &quot;Maintenance&quot; /TR &quot;[\\]&quot;[SERVICELOCATION]Maintenance.exe[\\]&quot;&quot; /ST [TASK_TIME]"
              Execute= "deferred"/>
<!-- rollback in case something went wrong -->
<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask_Rollback" Execute="rollback"  Return="ignore" Directory="SystemFolder" ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /Delete /TN &quot;Maintenance&quot; /F" />
<!-- removal of task -->
<CustomAction Id="RemoveScheduledTask" Return="ignore" Directory="SystemFolder" ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /Delete /TN &quot;Maintenance&quot; /F" Execute= "immediate"/>
```

which are queued as

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CreateScheduledTask_Rollback" Before="CreateScheduledTask"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="CreateScheduledTask"  Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="RemoveScheduledTask"  Before="RemoveFiles">
    <![CDATA[(REMOVE="ALL")]]>
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The `CreateScheduledTask`-action had a condition of `NOT Installed` which I removed for testing purposes.

Can anyone tell me, what I'd need to do, in order to have the task re-created when the upgrade setup rolls back? 
P.S.: I do not have access to the domain, username or password the task was originally created with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another rollback custom action for `RemoveScheduledTask` that does essentially what is in `CreateScheduledTask`. For example:

```
<CustomAction Id="RemoveScheduledTask_Rollback" Return="ignore" Directory="SystemFolder"
          ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /Create /RU &quot;[TASK_DOMAIN]\[TASK_USERNAME]&quot; /RP [TASK_PASSWORD] /SC DAILY /TN &quot;Maintenance&quot; /TR &quot;[\\]&quot;[SERVICELOCATION]Maintenance.exe[\\]&quot;&quot; /ST [TASK_TIME]"
          Execute="rollback" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="RemoveScheduledTask_Rollback" Before="RemoveScheduledTask"">
    REMOVE="ALL"
   </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

You will need access to the domain, username and password to create the task the same way it was originally. You can use the [Remember Property Pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern) to have the properties available during uninstall, although you'll want to add another couple actions to encrypt/decrypt the password before storing it probably.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the example and clarification. For security reasons I'm not going to store the credentials. Since a failed upgrade will also be followed by additional investigation (and most likely, a successful upgrade) this results in only a minor inconvenience.